# What does "|" do in Jython

Tags: python, bash, db2, jython

```
class Db2profile(Cmd):
    BIN_NAME = 'db2profile'

    @staticmethod

    def handler(output):
        return output.splitlines()

def set_db2_profile(executor, instance_home):
    #cmdline = '. ' + str(shell_interpreter.normalizePath(instance_home + Db2profile.BIN_NAME))
    cmdline = 'unset LIBPATH; . ' + str(shell_interpreter.normalizePath(instance_home + 
    Db2profile.BIN_NAME)) <= #this doesn't work

    return Db2profile(cmdline) | executor
```

Hi Folks, I'm very new to Python/Jython, hoping some one can help me out. 
Basically the code is trying to send some commands to bash to be executed (setting up db2 environs). It's part of HP's uCMDB discovery adapters for db2 databases.

What does `return Db2profile(cmdline) | executor` do? Usually `|` operator is a bitwise OR but according to Jython documentation the bitwise OR is `||`.

It also make no sense to do a bitwise operation on a string. Is it piping the output into another function?

Comment: Where did you get the `||` reference from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is the [bitwise OR operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), but it can be overloaded if the `Db2profile` class implements an [`__or__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__).

In all likelyhood `Cmd` implements that method; it can return it likes with the `executor` value as input; it is called as `Db2profile(cmdline).__or__(executor)`.

Comment: According to this, the bitwise operator OR in jython is || http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/OpsExpressPF.html or am i missing something here...

Comment: @Rillanon: that looks like an error; the sample code below it uses a single `|`. It would be a huge deviation from the Python standard syntax if it wasn't an error in that book.

Comment: @Rillanon: unfortunately it looks as if HP didn't grace us with an online copy of the uCMDB Jython documentation.

Comment: Yeah they are not very big on documenting anything... I think you are right, that give me some ideas to work with, thanks!